# How can I pass comments for each property in a property file dynamically

Tags: java

How can I dynamically put comments for each and every property in my application.properties. store() method will take only one comment only.

I have tried store() method but that didn't work as per my expectation as it only take a single comment.

application.properties

```
#this is comment 1
prop1=value1

#this is comment 2
prop2=value2
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't easily do it. You might be able to modify the writer to add the comments as it is writing out the file (advanced).

Comment: Where would these comments come from? Class `java.util.Properties` is basically a map, i.e. it holds keys and values. As far as I know, it doesn't have comments.

Comment: You could try this: https://coderanch.com/t/544562/java/save-properties-file-affecting-existing